# Can I get the original target name from an alias target?

Tags: cmake

If I create an alias target in CMake like

```
add_library(my::foo ALIAS my_foo)
```

is there any way to query the name of the underlying target name from the alias target?

My use case:

- A shared C++ codebase with several independent modules. The root folder of this codebase contains a `CMakeList.txt` to be added via `add_subdirectory` to the project using it. According to our convention e.g. `my_foo` will always be located in a subfolder named `my_foo`. Furthermore, `my_foo` will be exported as alias target `my::foo` and used as such in the project. Note that `my_foo` is always an `INTERFACE` target, so I cannot set any custom properties on it.
- We use conan to manage third party library dependencies. All modules that have such dependencies contain a `conanfile.txt`
- For convenience I want to write a function (located in the shared codebase's root CMakeList) that takes a list of module targets the project wants to use and scans all of them for conanfiles and sets up the dependencies for those used. I want to be able to pass `my::foo` as argument to that function but derive `my_foo` from that argument inside the function to get the corresponding folder name to scan for the conanfile

Any other suggestions that solve the problem according to my use case are welcome as well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alias target has a special property, where it stores name of the original target: [ALIASED_TARGET](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/ALIASED_TARGET.html).

```
get_target_property(my_foo_original my::foo ALIASED_TARGET)
message(STATUS "Alias my::foo refers to the target ${my_foo_original}")
```